# print an array got from twitter via php?

Tags: php, arrays, twitter, printing

I use this code to get many information about the a tweet

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
$tw_get=$connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => $tw_usr, 'count' => 1));
```

how can I print the array to be like this example :

```
        [id_str] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [created_at] => Thu May 10 14:08:36 +0000 2012
    [recipient_screen_name] => Infobot2012
    [recipient_id] => xxxxxxxx
    [sender_id] => xxxxxxxx
    [recipient] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => xxxxxxxx
            [id_str] => xxxxxxxx
            [default_profile] => 1
            [profile_use_background_image] => 1
            [location] => 
            [statuses_count] => 11
            [following] => 
            [utc_offset] => 
            [profile_sidebar_border_color] => C0DEED
            [listed_count] => 0

        )
    [text] => test
)
```

because it's printed like this :

> stdClass Object ( [created_at] => Fri Sep 01 16:10:42 +0000 2017 [id] => 9.0365133846191E+17 [id_str] => 903651338461908997 [text] => RT @SonyMobileNews: Engadget hands-on with Xperia XZ1 - includes 3D Creator, Predictive Capture and more youtube.com [truncated] => [entities] => stdClass Object ( [hashtags] => Array ( ) [symbols] => Array ( ) [user_mentions] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [screen_name] => SonyMobileNews [name] => Sony Xperia News [id] => 70888891 [id_str] => 70888891 [indices] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 18 ) ) ) [urls] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [url] => youtube.com [expanded_url] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KIOBponXMkY [display_url] => youtube.com/watch?v=KIOBpoâ€¦ [indices] => Array ( [0] => 105 [1] => 128 ) ) ) )

Answer (score 0):

use `<pre>` asuming your array is `$your_array` the code would be:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($your_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: of course :) , the print isn't 100% as I need , it adds  " public " before every item not as I want like this :  "[id_str] =>" 
how to solve this please ??